# How to capture the link provided in a Smartsheet share invitation mail

Tags: smartsheet-api

I regularly share a sheet. I send the invitation email. This email contains the link to the sheet. How can I get this link so I can store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the link to the sheet, you can get it by issuing a [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) request, which returns a [Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#sheet-object) object. Within the `Sheet` object, the `permalink` property specifies the hyperlink that can be used to access the sheet.

Request: `GET /sheets/{sheetId}`

Response:

```
{
  "id": 4583173393803140,
  "name": "sheet 1",
  "version": 6,
  "totalRowCount": 240,
  ...
  "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home?lx=pWNSDH9itjBXxBzFmyf-5w",
  ...
}
```

Please note, the URL specified by `permalink` property within a `Get Sheet` response will link to the sheet -- but it may not be the exact same URL that that's included in the email that the recipient receives in a sharing invitation email. I haven't tested this scenario, but it should be easy for you to compare the two URLs, should you choose to do so.

**UPDATE**

Per the information in the comments below, the value of the `permalink` property in a `Get Sheet` response is indeed different than the URL that's included in a sharing invitation email. The link in a sharing invitation email is a system-generated URL that's not available via API.

Comment: The permalink is not the same as the link in the mail. That's precisely the problem. I need the get the mail link...

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not possible. The link in the sharing invitation email is a system-generated link that’s not available via API.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate.
Thank you for this answer; I now know what to do.
Best,
JP

Comment: Happy to help; sorry it wasn't the answer you were hoping for. I've added this info as an "UPDATE" to my original answer to make it more discoverable (people don't always read through comment threads). If you wouldn't mind 'upvoting' the answer when you have time, that'd make others more likely to benefit from it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I clicked the "Votes" button. I hope this does the trick of "Upvoting" ...

Comment: Thanks JP -- but to 'upvote' an answer, you'll need to click the *^* arrow (i.e., up arrow) that's located just below the text "1 Answer" -- at the top of and to the left of where my answer begins. When you click that *^* arrow, you should see the number *0* change to the number *1*. Thanks!

Comment: @JPTollenboom you don't have the 15 rep required to upvote. But if this solves your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark button instead.

Comment: Ah, yes -- thank you @joanis. (I neglected to notice that JPTollenboom is a new user.)